# Proof that the fraction "round down" function is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-integration, borel-sets

I am trying to exhibit a Borel-measurable function which is positive on [0,1], i.e.

$$ f: [0,1]\rightarrow (0,\infty) $$

But which has lower Riemann integral equal to 0.  Here the lower Riemann integral is defined as supremum over all lower Riemann sums.

I guessed that the following function might work, which essentially takes every rational number and "rounds down" the numerator to 1:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/q & \text{ if } x = p/q \in \mathbb Q \text{ and } (p,q)=1 \\\\
x & \text{ if } x\not\in\mathbb Q \\\\
1 & \text{ if } x = 0 \end{cases} $$

On any partition we can find a point which gets arbitrarily small, so I think I have correctly found a function which is positive and Riemann-integrates to 0.  What I am unsure of is whether this function is Borel-measurable.

Suppose we take an open disc in the the codomain and apply the inverse image of $f$.  We need to know that this is a Borel set.  Certainly the inverse image of $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon)$ contains all irrationals in that interval.  And I imagine it contains all rationals of the form $1/q$ for some sufficiently large $q$.  But none of this sounds like any Borel set that I know of.

Comment: Consider (a) individual rationals in [0,1], (b) the (countable) union of these rationals, (c) the complement of that union, and (d)  the (countable) union of rationals with numerator $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \Delta B$ denote the symmetric difference $(A \setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)$.  It is helpful to observe that $f^{-1}((a,b)) \Delta (a,b)$ is a countable set (since $\{x: f(x) \neq x\}$ is countable). Let $A=f^{-1}((a,b))$ and $B=(a,b)$. Then $A =B \Delta (A\Delta B)$ (which is a set theoretic identity). Now $B$ is meaurable and $A\Delta B$ is measurable, so $B \Delta (A\Delta B)$ is measurable.